# Bijection $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ preserves collinearity $\iff \ \ f(x)=Ax+b$

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I don't know how to prove the following:

Bijection $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ preserves collinearity $\iff \ \ f(x)=Ax+b$, where $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $b$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\Leftarrow$ is easy, because such $f$ is an affine transformation of the plane and so it preserves collinearity (if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are collinear, then $f(x), f(y), f(z)$ are also collinear).

I have problems proving the reverse direction. Could you help me with that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a first suggestion, I'd look at the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$; if your claim is correct (and it is!) then $g$ must have the form $g(x) = Ax$. So you now need to show that if $f$ is a collinearity-preserving bijection fixing the origin, then $g$ is linear. Letting $e_1$ and $e_2$ denote the standard basis vectors, and $v_i = g(e_i)$, you know that each $v_i$ is nonzero (bijectivity), and that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not parallel. That last claim requires a little proof.

Suppose that $v_1 = c v_2$. Let $x = a e_1 + b e_2$ be any point of the plane. Rewrite

$x = (a+b)  \left( \frac{a}{a+b} e_1 + \frac{b}{a+b} e_2 \right) \\
 = (1 - (a+b)) {\mathbf 0} + (a+b)  \left( \frac{a}{a+b} e_1 + \frac{b}{a+b} e_2 \right),$

where ${\mathbf 0}$ denotes the origin. By collinearity, the point $\frac{a}{a+b} e_1 + \frac{b}{a+b} e_2$ which lies on the line between $e_1$ and $e_2$, is sent by $g$ to a point on the line between $v_1$ and $v_2$, i.e., the line through the origin and $v_1$. Call this point $sv_1$.

Similarly, the combination

$(1 - (a+b)) {\mathbf 0} + (a+b)  \left( \frac{a}{a+b} e_1 + \frac{b}{a+b} e_2 \right)$

is sent by $g$ to a point that lies on the line between $g({\mathbf 0})$ and $sv_1$, i.e., the line consisting of all multiples of $v_1$.

We've thus shown that if $v_1$ and $ v_2$ are parallel, then every point of the plane is sent, by $g$, to a point of the line consisting of all multiples of $v_1$. That contradicts the bijection assumption.

---

So: $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.   We can therefore build a linear transformation $T$ sending $v_i$ to $e_i$ $(i = 1, 2)$. Now look at the function

$h = T \circ g$.

$h$ is bijective, preserves collinearity, and leaves the origin, $e_1$, and $e_2$ fixed. By expressing an arbitrary point as a combination of combinations, as above, you can prove that $h$ is in fact the identity. But that means that $g = T$ and you are done.

---

Details for that last claim, for the sake of @CuriousKid:

> Lemma: Because $h$ is bijective and sends lines to lines, if $m$ and
>   $n$ are parallel and distinct, then $h(m)$ and $h(n)$ must also be
>   parallel and distinct.

Proof: Suppose not. Then let $P \in h(m) \cap h(n)$. Since $P \in h(m)$, there must be a point $A \in m$ with $h(A) = P$. Similarly, for some $B \in n$, we have $h(B) = P$. But then $h(A) = h(B)$, and because $h$ is bijective, we know that $A = B$. But this shows that $m$ and $n$ intersect, so that cannot be distinct and parallel.

> Corollary: if $m$ and $n$ are parallel, then $h(m)$ and $h(n)$ are
>   parallel.

Proof: If they are distinct, the Lemma proves this. If they are identical, then $h(m) = h(n)$, and hence they are parallel as well.

(The definition of "parallel" that I'm using is "either identical or disjoint"; this has the advantage of being an equivalence relation.)

---

Fact: because $h$ fixes the origin and $e_1$, it fixes the $x$-axis; similarly, it fixes the $y$-axis. (By this, I mean that applying $h$ to all points of the $x$-axis results in all points of the $x$-axis, not that they are individually fixed by $h$, i.e., $h(a, 0) = (b, 0)$ for some $b$, and $b$ is not necessarily $a$. (Yet.))

Applying the lemma, we see that $h$ sends horizontal and vertical lines to horizontal and vertical lines. (That is to say, if $m$ is horizontal, then $h(m)$ is also a horizontal line, but not necessarily the line $m$...at least not yet...)

Consider the line $y = 1$. It's sent to a horizontal line, by the preceding paragraph, and since $h(e_2) = e_2$, we see that it's sent to itself. So at least THAT horizontal line is fixed (setwise) by $h$. The same argument shows that the line $x = 1$ is sent (setwise) to itself by $h$. And that shows that the point $Q = (1, 1)$ is fixed, for it lies on both lines, and hence $h(Q)$ lies on both lines, hence $h(Q) = (1, 1)$.

We now have, in summary

> Lemma: All four corners of the unit square are fixed by $h$. The six lines formed by joining pairs of these are setwise fixed as well. And $h$ preserves parallelism.

[I should mention here that this argument that I'm gradually unwinding it closely modeled on an argument in Hartshorne's "*Foundations of Projective Geometry*", which I love.]

Now let's look at a point $(c, c)$ on the diagonal (with $c \ne 0, 1$, since we already know about those two). $h(c, c) = (d, d)$, because the line is setwise fixed. I want to show that $c = d$, i.e., that $h$, restricted to the diagonal $x = y$, is actually *pointwise* fixed.

Now $(c, c)$ lies on the line $n$ from $(1, 0)$ to $(c, c)$, namely $cx + (1-c)y - c = 0$. (Note that at least one of the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ here is nonzero, because we said $c \ne 0, 1$, making this the equation of a line rather than being degenerate.) Furthermore, $h(n)$ is parallel to $n$, but also contains $(1, 0) \in n$. Hence $h(n) = n$. Hence $(d, d)$ also lies on $n$. Since it lies on both $n$ and the diagonal, as does $(c, c)$, these points must be equal. Hence $c = d$. We've shown

> Prop: $h(a, a) = (a, a)$ for every $a$.

Now look at the line $m$ from $(a, 0)$ to $(a, a)$ defined by $x = a$. What can we say about $h(m)$? Well, it's parallel to $m$, and contains $(a, a)$, by the proposition. Hence it must equal $m$. So $h(a, 0) = (p, q)$ lies on the line $x = a$. So $p = a$. But it also lies on the $x$-axis (because that set is setwise fixed by $h$), so $q = 0$. Hence $h(a, 0) = (a, 0)$. A similar argument shows that each point on the $y$-axis remains fixed under $h$. So now we know

> Prop: $h$ fixes, pointwise, the diagonal $x = y$, and the 
>   lines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$.

Finally, for any point $(a, b)$, let $h(a, b) = (c, d)$. Since $(a, b)$ lies on the line $n$ defined by $x = a$, $(c, d)$ lies on $h(n)$, which must be parallel to $n$, i.e., must be vertical. But this vertical line also contains the point $(a, 0)$, because it lies on $n$ and is fixed by $h$. Hence $h(n)$ is a vertical line containing $(a, 0)$, which must be $x = a$. So $c = a$. A completely analogous argument shows that $d = b$, hence that $h(a, b) = (a, b)$. Since $(a, b)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $h$ is the identity, as required.

(I have to apologize --- I have no idea what my "combination of combinations" remark means in retrospect!)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question, though. How do we know that the line through $g(0)$ and $sv_1$ consists of all multiples of $v_1$ (which is the same as saying that it is the same line as the line through $0, \ v_1$)?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that $h$ is the identity without using linearity of $g$. Could you explain to me what you mean by combination of combinations? Is it $x = (a+b)  \left( \frac{a}{a+b} e_1 + \frac{b}{a+b} e_2 \right)$?

Comment: As you observe, $g({\mathbf 0}) = {\mathbf 0} = 0 v_1$. So the line through $g(0)$ and $sv_1$ is the line between $0v_1$ and $sv_1$, which is all multiples of $v_1$. Why? In general, the line between $P$ and $Q$ consists of all points of the form $aP + bQ$, where $a + b = 1$, or (by a slight shift of notation) of the form $(1-t)P + tQ$, where $t$ is any real. (These are called "affine combinations" of $P$ and $Q$). 

And when you say "f preserves collinearity", it amounts to saying that f, applied to any affine combination of $P$ and $Q$, produces an affine combination of $f(P)$ and $f(Q)$.

Comment: I know this is from a while ago, but I don't see how you prove $h$ is the identity without assuming $g$ is linear. Could you please explain this?

Comment: See my additions in the last several paragraphs of the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: How exactly does applying the lemma give the fixing-of-lines property you mention?

Comment: Also, is the $T$ you defined the identity map?

Comment: The horizontal line $x = a$ (call it $n$)  is parallel to the $x$-axis (call it $m$). The line $m$ is sent to itself (because $h$ fixes both $0$ and $e_1$), hence the line $n$, which it parallel to $m$, must be sent to something parallel to $n$. But...as I now observe, and you probably already noticed, that's not enough. I'll add some details. :)

Comment: $T$ is NOT necessarily the identity, no. Look at the case where $f(x, y) = (-y, x)$. Then $f(e_1) = e_2$ and $f(e_2) = e_1$, and $T$ is the inverse of this, which is clearly not the identity. (In fact, in this special case, $T = f$).

Comment: Extensive details added. I hope this clears things up. A diagram may help.

Comment: But in your example why can't we just use $\{e_2, e_1\}$ as a basis for the domain of $T$? I don't see why we can't just do this.

Comment: I'm trying to describe a linear transformation. If that transformation were the identity, then we'd have $T(e_1) = e_1$. But for my example, $T(e_1) = e_2$. Hence, it's not the identity transformation. It doesn't matter what basis you choose. Of course, if you write it down with respect to some well-chosen pair of bases, the MATRIX wrt those bases may be the identity matrix...but that doesn't make the transformation the identity transformation.

Comment: Oh right, that last part was my confusion. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think "Furthermore, $h(n)$ is parallel to $n$" is clear at that point.