# Bijection that preserve lines must be linear

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

There have been some past posts on this topic, but with no complete answer provided. Namely, if T is a bijection of the Euclidean plane that maps line segments to line segments (setwise) then T is an affine transformation, in the sense of linear algebra. What is the most elementary proof of this fact?

Comment: Unless I'm mis-remembering, there's a pretty elementary proof of this fact in Audin's *Geometry*. If there are no other answers by some ill-defined point in the future, I'll try to remember to post it.

Comment: Let $T(0)=x_0$. Then $T'(x)=T(x)-x_0$ gives a function that preserves lines and the origin, which should mean it is linear (I haven't checked the details). This makes $T$ the composition of a linear map and a translation, which means it is affine.

Answer (score 2):

Three points $u$, $v$ and $w$ in the plane are collinear iff the union of the line segments $[u, v]$, $[u, w]$ and $[v, w]$ is itself a line segment. So a bijection from the plane to itself that maps line segments to line segments preserves collinearity. See [Bijection $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ preserves collinearity $\iff \ \ f(x)=Ax+b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553114/bijection-f-mathbbr2-rightarrow-mathbbr2-preserves-collinearity-if/553151#553151) for the rest of the argument.